# How does bool version of boost::condition_variable::wait_until using a predicate behave?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, condition-variable

Trying to use the:

```
bool
wait_until(
    unique_lock<mutex>& lock,
    const chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& t,
    Predicate pred);
```

form of `boost::condition_variable::wait_until` (long story why not `std`). The documentation states that the effects of this are "As-if:"

```
while(!pred())
{
    if(!wait_until(lock,abs_time))
    {
        return pred();
    }
}
return true;
```

But the `wait_until(lock,abs_time)` form of `wait_until` actually returns a `cv_status` type defined as:

```
enum class cv_status;
{
  no_timeout,
  timeout
};
```

Since the `cv_status` type can't be implicitly cast to a `bool` (right?), what does the `if(!wait_until(lock,abs_time))` conditional from the "As-if" imply exactly? I imagine it's saying "if the wait times out, return the value of the predicate" but I don't get that from the form of the `if` statement and the `cv_status` return type of that `wait_until`.

Now, the `std` documentation "Equivalent to" seems to be exactly what I'd expect:

```
while (!pred()) {
    if (wait_until(lock, abs_time) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
        return pred();
    }
}
return true;
```

So is it safe to assume the `boost` documentation is just a little off and the implementation is as-stated in the `std` documentation?

Comment: It will return true if the result of the predicate is true before the timeout, or the false in case of timeout.  I.e. It will run the predicate every time the control variable is set, return true if the predicate is true, or wait to try again if false.  And return false if the entire operation times out before the predicate was true.  And while boost has contributed to the stl, boost is _not_ the stl.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think you're talking about the `wait_until(lock, abs_time, pred)` form, which I understand, but I'm actually asking about the `wait_until(lock, abs_time)` form referred to in the "As-if" (explanation) portion in the documentation. That form does not return a `bool` - it returns a `boost::cv_status` type. And if one assumed that `cv_status::no_timeout` was cast to a 0 (false) and `cv_status::timeout` was cast to a 1 (true), then the explanation is exact opposite of what I believe is the actual behavior.

Comment: @jeff as a guess, boost was designed with enum not enum class in mind.  And the docs reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be mixing up documentation¹.

In this sample code: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e835901b16af9647)</kbd>** (output: "Nay")

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::mutex m;
    boost::condition_variable cv;

    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(m);
    if (cv.wait_until(lk,
            boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + boost::chrono::seconds(1), 
            [] { return false; }))
    {
        std::cout << "Yay\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Nay\n";
    }
}
```

The return type of `wait_until` is actually bool. The implementation of that call is actually:

```
    template <class Clock, class Duration, class Predicate>
    bool
    wait_until(
            unique_lock<mutex>& lock,
            const chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& t,
            Predicate pred)
    {
        while (!pred())
        {
            if (wait_until(lock, t) == cv_status::timeout)
                return pred();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see, it deals with the `cv_status` type explicitly.

> Other than that it does look as if [sic] the "As-if" code is pseudo-code that assumes a bool-kind of return value. I agree this is technically "incorrect".

---

¹ See [image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, appreciate it. I was definitely being pedantic.

One thing I wish was in the documentation (maybe it is and I missed it): be sure your predicate does not need to lock on the same mutex your condition variable is using, else that opening `while(!pred())` tends to take, well, um, forever :-).